# Compute integer bounds to include scaled floating point values

Tags: c++, math

I am trying to compute integer array bounds that will include floating point limits divided by a scale. For example, if my origin is 0, my floating point maximum is 10 then my integer array bounds need to be 2. The obvious formula is to divide my bounds by the scale, giving the incorrect result of 1.

I need to divide the inclusive maximum values by the scale and add one if the division is an exact multiple.

I am running into a mismatch between the normal way to define and use integer array indexes and my desired way to use real value coordinates. I am trying to map inclusive real value coordinates into integer array indexes, using a scaling term.

(I am actually working with two dimensional maps, but the problem can be expressed more simply in one dimension.)

This is wrong:

```
    int get_array_size(double, scale, double maximum)
    {
       return std::ceil(maximum / scale); // Fails on exact multiples
    }
```

This is wasteful:

```
    int get_array_size(double, scale, double maximum)
    {
       return 1 + std::ceil(maximum / scale); // Allocates extra array memory
    }
```

This is ugly and I am not sure if it is correct:

```
    int get_array_size(double, scale, double maximum)
    {
       if (maximum % scale == 0) // I am not sure if this is correct
          return 1 + std::ceil(maximum / scale);
       else
          return std::ceil(maximum / scale); // Maybe I can eliminate the call to std::ceil?
    }
```

I am trying to get the value maximum / scale on every open ended interval ending at multiples of scale and 1 + maximum / scale on every interval from >= multiple of scale ending at < multiple of scale + 1. I am not sure how to correctly express this in mathematical terms or how to implement it in c++. I would be grateful if someone can clarify my understand and point me in the right direction.

Mathematically I think I am trying to define f(x, s) = y s.t. if s * n <= x and x < s * (n + 1) then y = n + 1. I want to implement this efficiently and respect the difference between <= and < comparison.

Comment: Does this need to handle negative coords at all?

Comment: Yes, I want to handle negative coordinates by applying an offset. At the implementation level the offset will map array indexes to a zero based array. My example shows the simple case for clarity.

Comment: If I want a real valued location at x, y the data will be stored in at array at location x / s, y / s. If s == 10, then location 10, 20 is at index location 1, 2 which requires an array size of 2, 3 if the array has zero indexing.

Comment: Yes, I think binning is a valid description. I am working with maps and want to specify all the locations (in real values) that are valid. It would be easier to implement if the limits were exclusive, but I want to be able to get the bin corresponding to the bottom right corner, so that has to be inclusive.

Comment: Okay. Your initial paragraph does not mention the scale. Can you include that detail and remove the second dimension from the question entirely since it just seems to muddy the waters.

Comment: When I went to implement testing code that would check locations in the map, I found it was really difficult to check the bottom right corner unless the map limits are inclusive. I would need to check width - ulp or something like that.

Comment: So index `i` represents values `scale*i <= x && x < scale*(i+1)`? Then the index for value `x` is `std::floor(x/scale)`. To make an array where the index of `maximum` is valid, it must have size at least `1+std::floor(maximum/scale)`. Right?

Comment: I've edited the question to be entirely in one dimension, even though I am actually working in two dimensions.

Comment: I can't prove that size at least 1+std::floor(maximum/scale) is correct. If that is true, I would not have a problem. I think that when maximum is not an integer multiple of scale, my size can be std::floor(maximum/scale), saving memory.

Comment: I suspect fencepost error there. If `maximum/scale` is 1.0, you need one element for both `0.0` and `maximum`? If `maximum/scale` is 2.0 and the array size is two, where do the three values `0.0`, `scale`, `2*scale` go?

Comment: I want to specify floating bounds that are inclusive on both ends, and allocate enough bins for that, and no more. I want to write testing code that checks the original floating point bounds (inclusively). The integer width needs to be approximately (upperBound - lowerBound) / scale and I am trying to get a formula that has no off-by-one errors.

Comment: Do you have your tests yet? Write it for non-edge cases and for edge cases. Then, check if your code works and call it a day. I believe TS' answer gets you there.

Comment: The code is coming together. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

The way I interpret this question, I think `maximum` and `scale` don't actually matter - what you are really asking about is how to correctly map from floats to ints with specific boundary conditions.  For example [0.0, 1.0) to 0, [1.0, 2.0) to 1, etc.  So the question becomes a bit simpler if we just consider `maximum / scale` to be a single quantity; I'll call it `t`.

I believe you actually want to use [`std::floor`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/floor) instead of `std::ceil`:

```
int scaled_coord_to_index(float t) {
    return std::floor(t);
}
```

And the size of your array should always be the maximum scaled coordinate + 1 (with negative values normalized to start at 0).

```
int array_size(float min_t, float max_t) {
    // NOTE: This will "anchor" your coords based on the most negative value.
    //       e.g. if that value is 1.6, then your bins will be [1.6, 2.6), [2.6, 3.6), etc.
    //       To change that behavior you could use std::floor(min_t) instead.
    return scaled_coord_to_index(max_t - min_t) + 1;
}
```

Comment: Binning and floating point mapping always makes me go cross eyed. I'm giving you an upvote until someone tells me otherwise.

Comment: Your interpretation adds clarity, thank you. I'll implement that solution and see if it works.